# ExifInterface not working with files from sdcard

Tags: android, kotlin

So I have some code to choose an image from phone gallery and display it in an ImageView and also use it's URI in ExifInterface and get the exif data.

But it seems that, only works for the images in internal storage and not for external storage like sdcard.

So here is what I got:

I have a button that when it's clicked, First it checkes to see if the app has READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission and if not it asks for it.

After it's granted with the permission it launches the function below :

```
private fun launchIntentForPhotos() {
    val gallery = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
    gallery.type = "image/*"
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(gallery, "Choose an image"), PICK_PHOTO_CODE)
}
```

and than for onActivityResult I have this:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_PHOTO_CODE) {
        imageUri = data?.data

        imageView.setImageResource(0)
        imageView.setImageURI(imageUri)

        showExif(imageUri)
    }
}
```

and finally the function for EXIF data:

```
private fun showExif(imageUri: Uri?) {

    val inputStream :InputStream

    try
    {

        inputStream = imageUri?.let { contentResolver.openInputStream(it) }!!
        val exifInterface = ExifInterface(inputStream)
        // Now you can extract any Exif tag you want
        // Assuming the image is a JPEG or supported raw format
        val imgWidthExif: String? = exifInterface?.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_WIDTH)
    }
    catch (e: IOException) {
        // Handle any errors
        Log.v(TAG, "ERROR")
        Toast.makeText(this, "Some went wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

The showExif doesn't work when selecting an image from external storage and also I get this error:

```
W/ImageView: resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content....
```

Can Someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?!

Comment: First: you do not need any permission using ACTION_PICK.

Comment: Second: use the obtained uri to read the exif info. Keep far away from constructs like get real path from uri.

Comment: @blackapps Thank you for replying. I am using the obtained uri from ( imageUri = data?.data ) but it's not working for the images selected from sdcards!

Comment: It is unclear what exactly does not work.

Comment: @blackapps When we we select an image from an sdcard, the uri which is passed to the inputstream in the showexif function, doesn not work and also the image view cannot resolve the Uri and gives me the error which I mentioned above.

Comment: You are messing around trying to get real path from uri. Stop doing such things. Use the obtained uri directly. And you do not nead read permissions if you use the uri.

Comment: @blackapps the getRealPathFromURI is only used for getting the file name. I do not have any problems there. the obtained Uri ( imageUri = data?.data) is used for both the imageview and the showExif function. The problem is with the obtained Uri!

Comment: because the getRealPathFromURI part was not relevant to the problem, I remvoed it.

Comment: Ok. You told us only one uri half. Please post two full uries. One from sd card.

Comment: `imageView.setImageURI(imageUri)` Does that work for both uries? Do you get an UOException? If so then toast e.getMessage().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution and it works fine for me!

Instead of using ACTION_PICK I used ACTION_GET_CONTENT like this:

```js
private fun launchIntentForPhotos() {
        val gallery = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        gallery.type = "image/*"
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(gallery, "Choose an image"), PICK_PHOTO_CODE)
    }
```